# UK Visitor visa from USA

Tags: visas, uk

I have applied UK visiting visa on March 4th 2019. Application reached on March 5th. On March 20th i got email saying

> Dear XXXX
>
> Your UK visa application has been despatched from the UK Visa Section.
>
> If you are applying from China, Europe, North & West Africa and GCC
> countries:
>
> - And you submitted your application at a visa application centre - You will receive an email within 1-2 working days from TLS or VFS on
>   collecting your decision. Please ensure you check your e-mail account
>   and do not attend the VAC until you are advised to.
>
> VAC - Visa Application Centre.
>
> OR
>
> - You submitted your application at the following locations:  Cyprus, Gibraltar, Finland, Sweden, Denmark, Malta, Norway, Denmark and
>   Estonia,  you will receive an email from DHL within 1-2 working days
>   with your waybill number. You can track your application via the DHL
>   website using this waybill number.
>
> OR FOR APPLICATIONS FROM USA:
>
> If you applied via a US Department of Homeland Security Application
> Support Centre or a VFS Premium Application Centre and chose to have
> your passport mailed back to you directly, that will take place
> shortly.
>
> If you submitted your application via a VFS Premium Application Centre
> and chose to collect your passport in person at the end of the
> process, they will be in contact with you to provide further guidance.
>
> If anyone contacts you advising that your application is still under
> consideration or that they can influence the outcome of your
> application in any way, they cannot - please report any such approach
> to UKVI.
>
> You should not expect to receive any further emails from this office.
> Regards,
>
> UK Visa Section  Croydon

Until now i didn't get passports. i am tracking UPS return shipping label which i sent with the application. Its more than 8 days after i got email from the embassy. Did any one applied UK Visa recently. Any information will be appreciated

Comment: From where did you apply? Did you elect to have your passport mailed back to you? Doesn't one of the several-case statements in this email address your situation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for similar experiences which are not knowledge that will help future readers.